# How to free memory allocated by new[]?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, heap-memory

I'm currently trying to create vector-like container. It uses memory allocated by `new[]` as it's base. the problem arises when I need to expand the array. I allocate a bigger chunk of memory with `new[]`, then `memcpy` old memory into there and `delete[]` the old memory. Thing is, trying to store any pointer or any pointer-containing object inside result in memory corruption. So I need a way to free the memory used without destroying objects inside

Edit: Some code to understand the problem:

```
template<typename T>
class myvector
{
private:
 T* _data;
 size_t _size, _capacity;
 static constexpr float multiplier = 1.5;
public:

void expand()
{
    size_t e_size = sizeof(T);
    size_t old_capacity = this->_capacity;
    this->_capacity = (unsigned long)(float(this->_capacity) * myvector::multiplier);
    T *tmp = new T[this->_capacity];
    memcpy(tmp, this->_data, e_size * (old_capacity));
    // this will destroy all the objects inside the container
    // which will result in destruction of any allocated memory
    delete[] this->_data; 
    // so now we have an array of invalid pointers. fun time
    this->_data = tmp;
}
}
```

Comment: I think the title of your question is a bit misleading, since you already know how to use `delete[]` and that it destroys the contents of the array. Maybe provide some code to illustrate the problem, but I think the problem is how you copy the memory. You shouldn't copy, but move-construct the objects when resizing.

Comment: Maybe share some code, as this would help to understand what you do

Comment: "then memcpy old memory into there " - That will not work with non-POD C++ types as it won't correctly call constructors/destructors.

Comment: `memcpy` can only be used with [trivially-copyable objects](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable).  It is not suitable for objects with user-defined destructors (or constructors, or assignment operators).

Comment: "So I need a way to free the memory used without destroying objects inside"  No you do not, you just need to fix incorrect way of object's movings from old storage to the new. classical XY problem

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `myvector` provide that `std::vector` does not?

Comment: @Eljay -- it provides practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to free memory allocated by new[]?

Using `delete[]`. This must be done before the pointer value is lost, and it must be done after the last use of the pointer value. And it must be done exactly once. And it must not be done for any other pointer than one that was returned by array `new`.

> Thing is, trying to store any pointer or any pointer-containing object inside result in memory corruption.

Then there is a bug in how you use the objects. Storing such objects in your template should by itself not be a problem.

> So I need a way to free the memory used without destroying objects inside

That is simply not possible. An object cannot exist without storage (except for special cases that don't apply here).

> ```
> delete[] this->_data; 
> // so now we have an array of invalid pointers. fun time
> ```

Why would there be an array of invalid pointers? Do the pointers in the array point to `this->_data`?

Indeed, your data structure does not have stable addresses for its elements. Expansion will invalidate any references to the elements. If you need such stability, then you must use a node based data structure such as a linked list.

---

Your template does have a limitation that it is well defined only for trivially copyable classes. Perhaps you've overlooked this limitation. It is easy to get rid of this limitation: Simply use `std::copy` (or perhaps `std::move` from `<algorithm>`, depending on exception safety guarantees that you need) instead of `std::memcpy`.